# Problems inserting footer in Excel - OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am sending Excel files as memory stream, editing them and then send them back to the browser so they open in client office program (Microsoft Excel). In the editing process I add footer on all excel sheets in the workbook. The inserting of footers works as it should most of the time, but it fails if the Excel - file I edit has many "complicated" sheets with graphs etc in it. This is the code I use for inserting footer

```
// Adds footer to all sheets in the workbook except the one inserted by code       
private static void AddFooterToAllSheets(SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument, string footerText, string sheetTitle)
{
    var workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    var workbook = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook;
    var sheetIndex = 0;

    //variable worksheetpart is not used in code, but added here because of looping
    foreach (var worksheetpart in workbook.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
    {
        string sheetName = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().ElementAt(sheetIndex).Name;
        if (sheetName.Equals(sheetTitle))
        {
            sheetIndex++;
            continue;
        }

        InsertHeaderFooter(spreadSheetDocument, sheetName, footerText, HeaderType.AllFooter);
        sheetIndex++;
    }
}


public static void InsertHeaderFooter(SpreadsheetDocument document, string sheetName, string textToInsert, HeaderType type)
{
    var wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

    // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use 
    // that Sheet object to retrieve a reference to 
    // the appropriate worksheet.
    var theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (theSheet == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var wsPart = (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));
    var ws = wsPart.Worksheet;

    // Worksheet is nothing? You have a damaged workbook!
    if (ws == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve a reference to the header/footer node, if it exists.
    var hf = ws.Descendants<HeaderFooter>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (hf == null)
    {
        hf = new HeaderFooter();
        ws.AppendChild<HeaderFooter>(hf);
    }

    // The HeaderFooter node should be there, at this point!
    if (hf != null)
    {
        // You've found the node. Now add the header or footer.
        // Deal with the attributes first:
        switch (type)
        {
            case HeaderType.EvenHeader:
            case HeaderType.EvenFooter:
            case HeaderType.OddHeader:
            case HeaderType.OddFooter:
                // Even or odd only? Add a differentOddEven attribute and set 
                // it to "1".
                hf.DifferentOddEven = true;
                break;

            case HeaderType.FirstFooter:
            case HeaderType.FirstHeader:
                hf.DifferentFirst = true;
                break;
        }

        switch (type)
        {
            // This code creates new header elements, even if they
            // already exist. Either way, you end up with a 
            // "fresh" element.
            case HeaderType.AllHeader:
                hf.EvenHeader = new EvenHeader { Text = textToInsert };

                hf.OddHeader = new OddHeader { Text = textToInsert };
                break;

            case HeaderType.AllFooter:
                hf.EvenFooter = new EvenFooter { Text = textToInsert };

                hf.OddFooter = new OddFooter { Text = textToInsert };
                break;

            case HeaderType.EvenFooter:
                hf.EvenFooter = new EvenFooter { Text = textToInsert };
                break;

            case HeaderType.EvenHeader:
                hf.EvenHeader = new EvenHeader { Text = textToInsert };
                break;

            case HeaderType.OddFooter:
                hf.OddFooter = new OddFooter { Text = textToInsert };
                break;

            case HeaderType.OddHeader:
                hf.OddHeader = new OddHeader { Text = textToInsert };
                break;

            case HeaderType.FirstHeader:
                hf.FirstHeader = new FirstHeader { Text = textToInsert };
                break;

            case HeaderType.FirstFooter:
                hf.FirstFooter = new FirstFooter { Text = textToInsert };
                break;
        }
    }
    ws.Save();
}
```

Trying to open the document gives me a message that the Excel-file is corrupt. The error I get in Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool when validating the corrupt file is this:

Error Node Type: Worskheet
Error Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml
Error Node Path: /x:worksheet[1]
Related Node Type: HeaderFooter

Description: The element has unexpected child element 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main:headerFooter'.

Comment: "It fails if the Excel - file I edit has many "complicated" sheets with graphs etc in it".  I think your first step is to figure out when the program actually fails (e.g. the sheet contains a chart), then we can start to figure you why it's failing

Comment: Most of the times I get problems with "The 'shapeId' is not declared, and after inserting my footer I get The element has unexpected child element.

Comment: I also have the same problem. When trying to open excel files with comments it says the file has corrupted data. Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public class GeneratedClass
    {
        private static System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String, OpenXmlPart> UriPartDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, OpenXmlPart>();
        private static System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String, DataPart> UriNewDataPartDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, DataPart>();
        private static SpreadsheetDocument document;

        public static void ChangePackage(string filePath)
        {
            using (document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
            {
                ChangeParts();
            }
        }

        private static void ChangeParts()
        {
            //Stores the referrences to all the parts in a dictionary.
            BuildUriPartDictionary();
            //Adds new parts or new relationships.
            AddParts();
            //Changes the contents of the specified parts.
            ChangeCoreFilePropertiesPart1(((CoreFilePropertiesPart)UriPartDictionary["/docProps/core.xml"]));
            ChangeWorksheetPart1(((WorksheetPart)UriPartDictionary["/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"]));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores the references to all the parts in the package.
        /// They could be retrieved by their URIs later.
        /// </summary>
        private static void BuildUriPartDictionary()
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.Queue<OpenXmlPartContainer> queue = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<OpenXmlPartContainer>();
            queue.Enqueue(document);
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var part in queue.Dequeue().Parts)
                {
                    if (!UriPartDictionary.Keys.Contains(part.OpenXmlPart.Uri.ToString()))
                    {
                        UriPartDictionary.Add(part.OpenXmlPart.Uri.ToString(), part.OpenXmlPart);
                        queue.Enqueue(part.OpenXmlPart);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds new parts or new relationship between parts.
        /// </summary>
        private static void AddParts()
        {
            //Generate new parts.
            VmlDrawingPart vmlDrawingPart1 = UriPartDictionary["/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"].AddNewPart<VmlDrawingPart>("rId2");
            GenerateVmlDrawingPart1Content(vmlDrawingPart1);

            ImagePart imagePart1 = vmlDrawingPart1.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/png", "rId1");
            GenerateImagePart1Content(imagePart1);

        }

        private static void GenerateVmlDrawingPart1Content(VmlDrawingPart vmlDrawingPart1)
        {
            System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(vmlDrawingPart1.GetStream(System.IO.FileMode.Create), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteRaw("<xml xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\"\r\n xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"\r\n xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">\r\n <o:shapelayout v:ext=\"edit\">\r\n  <o:idmap v:ext=\"edit\" data=\"1\"/>\r\n </o:shapelayout><v:shapetype id=\"_x0000_t75\" coordsize=\"21600,21600\" o:spt=\"75\"\r\n  o:preferrelative=\"t\" path=\"m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe\" filled=\"f\" stroked=\"f\">\r\n  <v:stroke joinstyle=\"miter\"/>\r\n  <v:formulas>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"sum @0 1 0\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"sum 0 0 @1\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"prod @2 1 2\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"prod @3 21600 pixelWidth\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"prod @3 21600 pixelHeight\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"sum @0 0 1\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"prod @6 1 2\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"prod @7 21600 pixelWidth\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"sum @8 21600 0\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"prod @7 21600 pixelHeight\"/>\r\n   <v:f eqn=\"sum @10 21600 0\"/>\r\n  </v:formulas>\r\n  <v:path o:extrusionok=\"f\" gradientshapeok=\"t\" o:connecttype=\"rect\"/>\r\n  <o:lock v:ext=\"edit\" aspectratio=\"t\"/>\r\n </v:shapetype><v:shape id=\"LH\" o:spid=\"_x0000_s1025\" type=\"#_x0000_t75\"\r\n  style=\';margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:207pt;height:156pt;\r\n  z-index:1\'>\r\n  <v:imagedata o:relid=\"rId1\" o:title=\"WOPI\"/>\r\n  <o:lock v:ext=\"edit\" rotation=\"t\"/>\r\n </v:shape></xml>");
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

        private static void GenerateImagePart1Content(ImagePart imagePart1)
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Capture.PNG");
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Save image to stream.
                image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                string imagePart1Data = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
                System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(imagePart1Data);
                imagePart1.FeedData(data);
                data.Close();
            }    

        }

        private static void ChangeCoreFilePropertiesPart1(CoreFilePropertiesPart coreFilePropertiesPart1)
        {
            var package = coreFilePropertiesPart1.OpenXmlPackage;
            package.PackageProperties.Modified = System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2015-07-30T03:03:22Z", System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);
        }

        private static void ChangeWorksheetPart1(WorksheetPart worksheetPart1)
        {
            Worksheet worksheet1 = worksheetPart1.Worksheet;

            HeaderFooter headerFooter1 = new HeaderFooter();
            OddHeader oddHeader1 = new OddHeader();
            oddHeader1.Text = "&L&G";

            headerFooter1.Append(oddHeader1);
            worksheet1.Append(headerFooter1);

            LegacyDrawingHeaderFooter legacyDrawingHeaderFooter1 = new LegacyDrawingHeaderFooter() { Id = "rId2" };
            worksheet1.Append(legacyDrawingHeaderFooter1);
        }

            private static System.IO.Stream GetBinaryDataStream(string base64String)
        {
            return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
        }



    }
}
```

Took it from: [Edward8520](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6eab2bee-9cde-4c12-a90b-f9b36f9fe614/create-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-an-image-on-the-first-header-with-open-xml?forum=oxmlsdkSearchhttps://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEV_enUS880US880&sxsrf=ALeKk03hkYPXmEpghPyYoZ2MUj7OVT79hA%3A1582590067278&ei=c2hUXo3REOKV_Qa96KbgDA&q=openxml+%22excel%22+insert+image+footer+-iceblue+-word+c%23&oq=openxml+%22excel%22+insert+image+footer+-iceblue+-word+c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3...122288.123245..123552...0.2..1.297.568.5j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.W1qYkd1te9g&ved=0ahUKEwjN1qO2t-vnAhXiSt8KHT20CcwQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, I found that in sheet1.xml I had "drawing" tag above "headerFoter", so in my case, the following code resolved the issue:

```
    var hf = ws.GetFirstChild<HeaderFooter>();
    if (hf == null)
    {
        hf = new HeaderFooter();

        var drawing = ws.GetFirstChild<Drawing>();
        if (drawing != null)
        {
            ws.InsertBefore(hf, drawing);
        }
        else
        {
            ws.AppendChild(hf);
        }
    }
```

Please pay attention to "InsertBefore" method (ws is Worksheet)